# has many through problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many-through

I have a has many through relationship with my groups and guests models. Here are the models:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :memberships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :guests, :through => :memberships

  def self.find(group)
    self.find_by_name(group).guest.collect{ |x| x.name  }
  end
end

class Guest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :groups, :through => :memberships
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :guest
  belongs_to :group
end
```

I am checking in console and here are the results:

```
ruby-1.9.2-head :001 > Group.first.guests
=> [] 

ruby-1.9.2-head :002 > Guest.first.groups
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
=>
```

Why doesn't the second one work? I tried inspecting the class of groups but it always returns an error:

```
ruby-1.9.2-head :005 > Guest.first.groups.class
NoMethodError: undefined method `guest' for nil:NilClass
```

Can anyone help me with this? I am actually just trying to follow this guide: http://millarian.com/programming/ruby-on-rails/quick-tip-has_many-through-checkboxes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `find` class method is using **guest** instead of **guests**:

```
self.find_by_name(group).guest.collect{ |x| x.name  }
```

I also noticed that you are overriding a built in ActiveRecord method, find, which is not recommended.

Comment: oh crap! i didn't realize i was accidentally overriding it. while i was refactoring i thought my method was find_group instead of find. LOL! thanks for that spot man.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because Guest.first is returning nil.  create a guest object and try it out.

Comment: @shreyas...in that case, Guest.first.groups will itself result in undefined method error..wont it?

Comment: Yes it will. which is what is happening. Looks like he has a group object but no guest object.